# Does const apply to all parameters passed into a function?

Tags: c++, constants

Given the following:

```
void abc(const int*, int*);
int x = 1;
int y = 2
abc(&x, &y);
```

Without knowing the definition of abc(), is there anyway of knowing what the values of x and y are after line 3 is executed?

This is what I believe to be true inside abc(),

x is a constant pointer that points to an int, therefore the value that is pointed to cannot change but the address that x points to CAN be changed.
Is that correct?

Also, does the const in the function header apply to only the first parameter? or does it apply to both?

Comment: You can use `std::is_same` to answer your title's question.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const), if not duplicate

Comment: "Does const apply to all parameters passed into a function?" - no. That would be a disaster.

Comment: It particular, you have to wonder how `memcpy` would work. The source obviously is `const`, the destination obviously is not.

Comment: `const` does NOT mean that a value cannot change.  It means that variable cannot be used to change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void abc(const int* a, int *b)
{
    *a = 1; // error - not allowed, *a is const
    a = b; // allowed, a is non-const
    *b = 1; // allowed, *b is non-const
    b = a; // error - not allowed, can't assign non-const pointer to a const pointer
    int c;
    b = &c; // allowed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Without knowing the definition of abc(), is there anyway of knowing
>   what the values of x and y are after line 3 is executed?

Sure. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> x is a constant pointer that points to an int, therefore the value
>   that is pointed to cannot change but the address that x points to CAN
>   be changed. Is that correct?

You read the type from right to left. So the first parameter is a pointer to a integer constant, and the second is a pointer to an integer.  So I'd rewrite your statement as:
x is a pointer to a const int, therefore the value that is pointed to cannot change because it is a const.

> Also, does the const in the function header apply to only the first
>   parameter? or does it apply to both?

The const applies to the first parameter and not to the second one. They are completely independent from each other.